How to get a summary of a PyTorch model that uses dictionary as an input
My model takes a dictionary as input, e.g. x = {'image': torch.tensor, 'number': torch.tensor}, the model looks like this:
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.imgmodule = ImgModule()
        self.nummodule = NumModule()
        self.predict = nn.Linear(input_size, 100)

    def forward(self, x):
        xImg = self.imgmodule(x['image'])
        xNum = self.nummodule(x['number'])
        x = self.predict(torch.cat([xImg, xNum], dim=1))
        return x    

How do I get model summary, similar to the summary provided in the pytorch-summary package?
So far I have tried using it like this:
from torchsummary import summary
summary(model, input_size=[(3, 224, 224), (1, )])

But I get an error:
TypeError: MyModel.forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given


Have you considered splitting inputs in the model? def forward(self, image, number): xImg = self.imgmodule(image). xNum = self.nummodule(number)

If I split the inputs like this, I would have to change training and inference code as well. I was wondering if it is possible to get model summary without making those changes.

You can make a wrapper model whose sole purpose is to take split inputs as arguments of its forward function, merge them in a dict and call MyModel with it. It's not a great solution but it'll take you 5 lines of code and nothing needs to be changed anywhere else

Maybe try using torchinfo instead of torchsummary (it's an updated version of torchsummary). They have this option of directly passing the input data - https://github.com/TylerYep/torchinfo?tab=readme-ov-file#multiple-inputs-w-different-data-types
I haven't tried the specific case of dictionary inputs, but it might just work if you pass it as input_data=your_input_dict.
